# [UIView _forgetDependentConstraint:]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I tried using NSZobie and all others. Still i face issues. can't able to find where app crashed. Please Help. thanks in advance.

```
 *** -[UIView _forgetDependentConstraint:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x208e0010
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x2503, 0x342b3468 CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 192, stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_B`enter code here`REAKPOINT, subcode=0xdefe)
    frame #0: 0x342b3468 CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 192
    frame #1: 0x3420af68 CoreFoundation`__forwarding_prep_0___ + 24
    frame #2: 0x364f24ba UIKit`_updateViewDependenciesForConstraint + 202
    frame #3: 0x364f9a2c UIKit`__72-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _removeRelevantConstraintsFromEngine:]_block_invoke_0 + 264
    frame #4: 0x34c65882 Foundation`-[NSISEngine withAutomaticOptimizationDisabled:] + 166
    frame #5: 0x364f98ee UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _removeRelevantConstraintsFromEngine:] + 94
    frame #6: 0x3629f4a0 UIKit`__UIViewWillBeRemovedFromSuperview + 588
    frame #7: 0x360e7848 UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 56
    frame #8: 0x36137f18 UIKit`-[UINavigationTransitionView _cleanupTransition] + 92
    frame #9: 0x360ceab2 UIKit`-[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 158
    frame #10: 0x361438ee UIKit`-[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 50
    frame #11: 0x35e78c00 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 208
    frame #12: 0x3c3f04b6 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 22
    frame #13: 0x3c3f51bc libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 224
    frame #14: 0x34284f3a CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1290
    frame #15: 0x341f7ebc CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
    frame #16: 0x341f7d48 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
    frame #17: 0x37dd02ea GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 74
    frame #18: 0x3610d300 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1120
    frame #19: 0x000521de MyApp®`main(argc=1, argv=0x2fdb3cf8) + 162 at main.m:6
    frame #20: 0x3c410b20 libdyld.dylib`start + 4
```

Comment: I tried using NSZobie and all others. Still i face issues. can't able to find where app crashed. Please Help. thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like you programmatically set up a constraint with a strong property or something?

Comment: i dont set any constraint with strong property. issues occurred when i came back to same view from anther view. no error when load it's first time.

Comment: pls add your viewWillAppear section

Comment: Nothing in viewwillappear methods.

Comment: I feel you are not using ARC, and you are not retaining of passing your previous object. In the meantime the previous object is released and then you accessing it.

Either you can refactor your code to use ARC or put retain or autorelease.

Comment: ok. will check it out.

Comment: Also try in thins way Go to Product > edit scheme >Diagnostics tap then check on enable Zombie objects

make a break point and go step by step to know which object is deallocated, it perhaps the pointer to your object has been removed then the OS has deallocated your object.

Comment: @ALL: i found issues, it's single tableview is binding with tableview and view. so that's silly mistake done by me. Thanks to all of you :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have UIAlertView or animations in view before came back to your view. It seems you are initalize a view with it's local variable, wihout having express use self delegate, or  you use removeFromSuperview for a view while actions still call it after remove.