# thread1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,address=) ios

Tags: ios, nszombie

I have been facing this issue on iOS simulator (6 & 7). Tried resetting phone but same problem.

Getting this error when loading another view controller

```
#   Event Type  ∆ RefCt RefCt   Timestamp   Responsible Library Responsible Caller
0   Malloc  +1  1   00:33.396.540   UIKit   UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
1   Retain  +1  2   00:33.397.009   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
2   Retain  +1  3   00:33.397.047   UIKit   UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
3   Retain  +1  4   00:33.397.064   UIKit   UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
    Retain/Release (2)          00:33.397.537   UIKit   -[UIViewController setView:]
6   Retain  +1  5   00:33.397.548   UIKit   -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]
7   Release -1  4   00:33.397.592   UIKit   -[UINibDecoder finishDecoding]
    Release (2) -2      00:33.397.647   UIKit   -[UINibDecoder finishDecoding]
10  Release -1  1   00:33.397.712   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
11  Release -1  0   00:33.409.138   UIKit   _UIApplicationHandleEvent
12  Zombie      -1  00:35.524.392   UIKit   ___updateViewDependenciesForConstraint_block_invoke_0
```

Tried profiler, zombie got below error but unable to process further. Can someone guide next steps?

An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated `UIView` object (zombie) at address: `0xbede440`.

```
updateViewDependenciesForConstraint_block_invoke_0+0x4d"
+0x3f   movl                2704706(%edi), %ecx
+0x45   movl                %eax, 8(%esp)
+0x49   movl                %ecx, 4(%esp)
+0x4d   movl                %esi, (%esp)
+0x50   calll               "DYLD-STUB$$objc_msgSend"
+0x55   addl                $16, %esp
+0x58   popl                %esi`enter code here`
+0x59   popl                %edi
+0x5a   popl                %ebp
+0x5b   ret  
+0x5c   nopl                (%eax)
```

Sample code

```
#pragma mark UITableViewDelegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)tableIndexPath {  

//Logic for validation 
XXXXXXXXXXx

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ADDXXXX" sender:self];
        return;

}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ADDXXXX"]){
        ADDXXXX *myVC = [segue destinationViewController];
        myVC.setXXX
        NSLog(@"INIT %p", self);    
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217233/thread-1-exc-bad-access-code-1-address-0x30000008

Comment: provide more infromation

Comment: iPatel - tried above steps came to this zombie statement. Need help to understand and resolve

Comment: iDev - Updated my question with details. Error occurred when opening up another ViewController.

Comment: can u post the code where you are showing another view controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, was able to resolve it by referring to this thread in stack overflow. Thanks all for your response.

[[UIView _forgetDependentConstraint:]: message sent to deallocated instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218248/uiview-forgetdependentconstraint-message-sent-to-deallocated-instance)